# TimeZone conversion problems .Net Dataset WebService

Tags: .net, web-services, dataset, data-conversion

I am accessing a webservice in .net which returns a dataset.

Looking at the xml from the webservice it shows a date as follows

```
2012-11-16T00:00:00-05:00
```

My computers timezone is GMT+1, you can see the date from the XML has the -5

I am using a webreference in VS2005 which gives me a dataset.

When I look at the date from the dataset it says it is 05:00

I was expecting 00:00 value and am unsure the proper way to convert.

I could simply subtract 5 hours, but not sure that will hold when daylight savings changes again.

Ive done a lot of googling and found similar problems when using datareader and how to fix it, but noone talking about what to do when it gets serialized into an entire dataset.

Comment: Why were you expecting `00:00` when the timezones are different? Though I would expect it to be `06:00` rather than `05:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is providing the *local* value, which is 2012-11-16T05:00:00Z. It sounds like the deserialization is then converting that into a `DateTime` in UTC... check the [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) property of the `DateTime` you've got... if it's `Utc` then it all makes sense, and you're getting the correct *instant in time* represented in the XML.

It's not clear what you're expecting, or what's posting the data, or what value you really need from it. If you can change the deserialization code to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, that would preserve both pieces of information.

Comment: I cant change anything on the webservice. The -5 is due to the location of the server, thats there GMT offset. I know for certain that particular date that I showed the XML is supposed to be interpereted by my location as 00:00 in my timezone which is GMT+1. I dont know how to go about changing the deserialization code as it is autogenerated by VisualStudio... any pointers would be nice

Comment: The type is datetime.unspecified

Comment: "I know for certain that particular date that I showed the XML is supposed to be interpereted by my location as 00:00 in my timezone which is GMT+1." - Why? How? It's very unclear what data this is meant to represent. It sounds like the web service *should* be just providing a local value. Will the value *always* be midnight? Is it just meant to represent a date?

Comment: There is an application made by the same company that runs the webservice. The app is dotnet. It reads this specific record and in the GUI presents the time as 00:00. I dont have source for the app so Im unsure how they are converting it. Im trying to make an app in dotnet and present the same time they are presenting to the user. As I said above, the raw XML shows 2012-11-16T00:00:00-05:00, but when I display the dotnet datetime from the dataset that is returned from the webservice/webreference it shows as 05:00, Im clueless how to go about properly converting.. hope this is more clearer.

Comment: Basically I guess I had 2 problems, I didnt quite understand representation of timezones in date. And the webservice isnt quite set up for other timezones. I ended up taking the date returned and converting it to the same timezone as the server. Now I get the date correct. I gave points to Jon because he spent the most time trying to help me. Thanks to both of you!